# Pre-computing min/max for interval queries?

Tags: data-structures

I'm basically trying to figure out if the following problem has a common name and/or a standard solution in computer science.

Let assume we're given $N$ two-dimensional tuples $(x_i, y_i)$. This data is fixed/static and we want to pre-compute a data structure that allows to run interval queries returning the max or min w.r.t. $y$ in the specified $x$ interval. For instance, for a given interval $[x_{lower}, x_{upper}]$ the query should return the min or max $y_i$ for all tuples satisfying $x_{lower} \leq x_i \leq x_{upper}$.

The obvious solutions are:

- A naive linear scan, which would have a complexity of $O(N)$.
- A brute-force pre-computing solution would pre-compute the min/max for all possible $[x_{lower}, x_{upper}]$ pairs, which would have $O(N^2)$ in terms of runtime and memory complexity.

It feels like there should be a smart solution achieving sub-linear query complexity without the $O(N^2)$ complexity of a brute-force pre-computation?

Comment: One category for problems like this is [geometric query problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry#Geometric_query_problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be to store the tuples in a balanced binary search tree, using $x$ as the key.  Augment that data structure to store in each node the maximum and minimum value of $y$, among all tuples that are stored in the subtree rooted at that node.  You can construct such a data structure in $O(N \log N)$ time (preprocessing).  Once you've done so, this data structure will allow you to answer interval queries in $O(\log N)$ time.  If you also want to support interval queries on $y$, make a second tree, this one using $y$ as the key.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that my mistake was to search for "interval query" instead of ["range query"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_query_(data_structures)). This term has revealed an relationship to [range minimum queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) and [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), which seem to be very similar to what you are suggesting.